# multiple collectionviews on same screen in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using PSUICollectionView in my app in which gallery with images thumbs are loaded with horizontal scrollview.
Now I need two more collectionviews(galleries) to show two other types of pictures.

Can anyone please help me out ??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple**. Just add the views like you would any other UIView's. Set their frames correctly, they should work.

Keep an outlet to each of them, then you can check to see which one of them is calling a delegate / data source method.

Comment: I need all three collection views at once without any condition. So they all must call delegate/data source method at once. How do i implement that??

Comment: In your delegate/data source methods, check to see which object is asking and return the appropriate information.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of data source/delegate methods for multiple collection views ?? And i think there is no need to implement delegate method as i just want to show the images and no action needed for each cell.

Comment: but I m not able to set outlet of collectionview just like giving to a tableview

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by adding some lines of code in delegate and data source methods as follows -

```
    // setting tag
    
   [self.imageCollection setTag:1];
    
   [self.finishImageCollection setTag:2];
    
   [self.prevImageCollection setTag:3];
```

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Collection View Data Source

```
 - (NSString *)formatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row+1];
   }

  // Populating cells 
  - (PSUICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView        cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ImageGridCell *cell = [collectionView    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(collectionView.tag==1){
     cell.statusImage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
     cell.imageThumb.image = [self.startImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }

   if(collectionView.tag==2){
    cell.statusImage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    cell.imageThumb.image = [self.finishImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }

   if(collectionView.tag==3){
    cell.statusImage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    cell.imageThumb.image = [self.prevImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }
   return cell;
  }

   - (NSInteger)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   int imgCount;
   if(collectionView.tag==1)
   {
    [self loadStartPictures];
    imgCount=self.startImages.count;
   }
   if(collectionView.tag==2)
   {
    [self loadFinishPictures];
    imgCount=[self.finishImages count];
   }
   if(collectionView.tag==3)
   {
    [self loadSupervisorPictures];
    imgCount=[self.prevImages count];
   }
   return imgCount;
  }


  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Collection View Delegate

  - (void)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   self.allImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   UIImage *imageAtIndexPath;
   NSLog(@"Delegate cell %@ : SELECTED", [self formatIndexPath:indexPath]);
   ImageGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.label.backgroundColor=[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor];

   if(collectionView.tag==1){
    imageAtIndexPath=[self.startImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
  if(collectionView.tag==2){
    imageAtIndexPath=[self.finishImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
  if(collectionView.tag==3){
    imageAtIndexPath=[self.supervisorImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
 }
```